# Restructure csv file

Tags: text-processing, csv

Here is an example of the data I'd like to modify:

```
John,,
bim,bam,boom
tim,tam,toom
lam,loom,lim
Mary,,
pam,pim,poom
dam,dim,doom*
```

I try to achieve this:

```
John,bim,bam,boom
John,tim,tam,toom
John,lam,loom,lim
Mary,pam,pim,poom
Mary,dam,dim,doom
```

When a name is alone on a line, it becomes a new column in all the rows below til the next name with the same pattern occurs.

I wonder if awk or another tool could help but I'm a bit lost.

I try to make a condition (if columns 2 and 3 are empty, do something) but that looks a bit complicated for me right now.

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please, give us some example of what you tried so far.

Comment: Of course. I tested the pattern with

Comment: Of course. Here it is. I tested the pattern with: awk -F, '/,,/ {print $1}' file1 and now I try to put use each of these $1 to make a new column in the following lines until the pattern reappears. But I struggle to do this. Maybe a while condition ("while I have not this /,,/ on a line").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are thinking on the right lines:

> I try to make a condition (if columns 2 and 3 are empty, do something)

Specifically,

- if columns 2 and 3 are empty, save the value of column 1 and continue
- otherwise, prepend the saved value to the line and print it (there are several `awk`ish ways to do this)

So for example

```
awk -F, '$2=="" && $3=="" {pfx=$1; next} {print pfx "," $0}' file.csv
```

or more idiomatically using the `FS` field separator variable

```
awk -F, '$2=="" && $3=="" {pfx=$1; next} {$0 = pfx FS $0; print}' file.csv
```

or (since the default action - when a rule evaluates true or `1` - is to print the record)

```
awk -F, '$2=="" && $3=="" {pfx=$1; next} {$0 = pfx FS $0} 1' file.csv
John,bim,bam,boom
John,tim,tam,toom
John,lam,loom,lim
Mary,pam,pim,poom
Mary,dam,dim,doom
```

Comment: I would use the OFS `awk -F, -v OFS=, '... {print pfx, $0}'`

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, it's very helpful to me!

Answer (score 2):

Perl alternative:

```
$ perl -F',' -lane 'if(@F == 1){$prefix = sprintf("%s,",@F);next;};print $prefix . $_' input.csv
John,bim,bam,boom
John,tim,tam,toom
John,lam,loom,lim
Mary,pam,pim,poom
Mary,dam,dim,doom
```

This operates on the premise that each line is split into array of elements using `,` as operator, and if there's only one item in that array,we use that line as prefix and go to next line. Other lines that are longer than 1 element will get prefix appended to them. Naturally, the prefix changes if and only if the array is of length 1.

Or shorter, using `shift` as suggested by Glenn Jackman:

```
$ perl -F',' -lane 'if(@F == 1){$prefix = shift @F;next;};print $prefix . "," . $_' input.csv
```

Or

```
$ perl -F, -lane '$,=","; if (1 == @F) {$name = shift @F} else {print $name, @F}' input.csv
```

Comment: @Theophrastus Fixed. Thank you for pointing out  the mistake

Comment: A little more succinct: `perl -F, -lane '$,=","; if (1 == @F) {$name = shift @F} else {print $name, @F}' file`

Comment: My first suggestion misses the first comma.

Comment: @glennjackman interesting, so  `@F`  in `(1 == @F)` is automatically evaluated as scalar  ?

Comment: A list in *scalar context* is taken as the number of elements: `perl -le '@l=(1,2,3,4); print @l; print 0+@l'` -- note that can harm readability: for production code I would use `scalar()`